# vertx auth2 working example

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, vert.x

I'm trying to make at least something from the `vert.x` official docs.

what exactly means [here](http://www.julienviet.com/vertx/docs/vertx-auth-oauth2/java/)

The **code**:

```
String code = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // the code is provided as a url parameter by github callback call

oauth2.getToken(new JsonObject().put("code", code).put("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:8080/callback"), res -> {
  if (res.failed()) {
    // error, the code provided is not valid
  } else {
    // save the token and continue...
  }
});
```

I believe from there

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2,

Authorization flow:

I suppose to send an authorization **code** to github/google to obtain an access **token** (that is my ultimate goal). Then that code is the authorization code?

I suppose to receive that code, I need to send first my user/credentials as first step? This step seems is missed.

**The question is.. what is the full flow/code to get the oauth token for github for example?**

--

My best what I could do:

1. Send redirect to github login page sending my credentials and the instruction how to call me back (the /auth-callback url on my server app)

   ```
     oauth2 = GithubAuth.create(vertx, clientId, applicationSecret);
     final String authorizationURI = oauth2.authorizeURL(new JsonObject()
               .put("redirect_uri", DOMAIN + ":" + PORT + "/auth-callback")
               .put("scope", "notifications")
               .put("state", "3(#0/!~"));

           context.response().putHeader("Location", authorizationURI)
               .setStatusCode(302)
               .end();
   ```
2. When I press enter on login I expect to get a call back.. and receive the ... **authorization code**? where it is??

So I do:

```
           router.get("/auth-callback/").handler( (RoutingContext context) -> {

            oauth2.getToken(tokenConfig, res -> {
                if (res.failed()) {
                    System.err.println("Access Token Error: " + res.cause().getMessage());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Got access");
                    // Get the access token object (the authorization code is given from the previous step).
                    final AccessToken token = res.result();

                    System.out.println("Got a token! " + token.toString());
                }
            });

        }
    );
```

So.. as result I never get called back by this url. Seems because .get(.. did not match the /auth-callback&scope=notifications&state=.. etc. all that param. What is the proper .get?

What is the tokenConfig supposed to be. This suppose to contain the **authentication code** ?

Like I said: one working example would be nice. The doc seems does not help much.

Answer (score 3):

Oauth2 specified several flows to get a token. The most common are the access code and password flow. When working with web applications that are interactive (require user interaction, not api endpoints) you will probably want to use the access code flow (code for short).

In this flow there is a sequence you need to follow in order to get a token. A detailed tutorial for GitHub can be seen here:

http://vertx-tutorials.jetdrone.xyz/tutorials/oauth2/github/

Comment: Hi, link broken: 404

Comment: fixed, sorry about that.

Comment: thx! i'm more interested in interactive scenario. I should not register app for that one?

Comment: The tutorial example is interactive, by that i mean that the user needs to interact with the github webpage to authorize the app. Are you referring to non interactive, for example an API? Where you already have an oauth2 token?

Comment: i mean: to interact with the github web-page just to get a token as a prove that user has registered there to go with that token to register / login to another system. for example I use Google account to login to StackOverflow. I do not need to register the app for that.

Comment: What you’re asking is the realm of user management and by no means a feature of oauth2. What oauth2 does is authorization and using the auth code flow it allows you to externalize the authentication to a 3rd party which can provide you a simple piece of information which is the user id.

Answer (score 1):

`tokenConfig` is a JsonObject which will have your code and redirect_uri.

Try this code, it works for me:

```
router.get("/login").handler(routingContext -> {
    routingContext.response().putHeader("Location", authorizationURI)
            .setStatusCode(302)
            .end();
});

router.get("/auth-callback").handler(routingContext -> {
    JsonObject tokenConfig = new JsonObject();
    tokenConfig.put("code", routingContext.request().params().get("code"));
    tokenConfig.put("redirect_uri", authorizationURI);
    oauth2.getToken(tokenConfig, res -> {
        if (res.failed()) {
            System.err.println("Access Token Error: " + res.cause().getMessage());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Got access");
            // Get the access token object (the authorization code is given from the previous step).
            final AccessToken token = res.result();

            System.out.println("Got a token! " + token.toString());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks! the authorizationURI is /auth-callback ? params().get("code") - null

Comment: It is your application URL where GitHub will redirect you back when auth is done. So yes, its the callback